# jQuery POST: setting Content-Type to be text/plain

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out why this isn't working. On the server, I have this:

```
@app.route('/message', methods=['POST'])
def print_post():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/plain':
        logging.warning(request.data)
        return "Text Message: " + request.data
    else:
        logging.warning('didnt work')
        return 'Unsupported Media Type'
```

I'm sending this request through the browser:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://localhost:8090/message",
    data: 'this is a message'
    contentType: 'test/plain'
})
```

But I keep getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is this typo comma is missing after `data: 'this is a message'` and `contentType: 'test/plain'` this should be 'text/plain'?

Comment: The problem with these kind of question, that the title is a great question but the actual problem stated in the body of the question is an embarrassment to the OP.. so how should one vote? up or down? I say **up** because of the importance of the question itself, even if the problem here was a typo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing a comma after your `data` property in the ajax call, and `contentType: 'text/plain'`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://localhost:8090/message",
    data: 'this is a message', // <-- Put comma here
    contentType: 'text/plain'
})
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! I would appreciate it!